# jQuery bxSlider Carousel - incorrect animation on last slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, bxslider

I'm using bxSlider with these settings:

```
var slider = jQuery('#carousel').bxSlider({
    slideWidth: 400,
    slideMargin: 25,
    maxSlides: 3,
    moveSlides: 1,
    useCSS: false,
    controls : true,
    nextText : "<span class=\"icon-arrowright\"></span>",
    prevText : "<span class=\"icon-arrowleft\"></span>",
    infiniteLoop: false,
    hideControlOnEnd: true,
    touchEnabled: true,
    responsive: true,
    pager: false,
)};
```

In total I have between a minimum of 3 and a maximum of 6 slides. The problem I have is that the last slide moves incorrectly. The first slide goes left by `-425px (slideWidth+slideMargin)`. However, the last slide moves left only by `-800px`, not `-850px` as it should. Now, if I close or open Firefox (which I think re-initialize the javascript on the page) the carousel last slide snaps to `-850px` automatically.

So, I thought: let's identify the lastSlide and move the slide with -50px to the left:

```
onSlideAfter: function() {
    var total = Math.ceil(slider.getSlideCount()/3);
    var current = slider.getCurrentSlide();
    var lastslide = Math.ceil(total / current);
    var text = 'it works';
       if (current == total) { // Last slide
           jQuery('#carousel #post-sticky:first-of-type').css('margin-left','-50px');
           console.log(text); // this shows on the last-slide but the code above does move the slide;
       }
    }
```

Now, the console.log text appears when I reach the last slide, but the slide doesn't move left. What I did next was to include `slider.redrawSlider();` in the above `if` statement. This snaps the carousel in place but the effect is quite ugly. And after I click on previous and then on next, it doesn't work anymore.

Any ideas in solving this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle to display the issue?

Comment: Yes, first I want to try the same setup with another slider to make sure that it's now a bxSlider bug. If it's the same I'll create a fiddle.